# Powershell problem using .NET Replication Management Objects RMO

Tags: .net, sql-server, powershell, replication

I am trying to automate the reinitialization of several replication 
subscriptions that pull anonymously from the distribution server. I am 
working on this project in Powershell and I believe I am having a 
64bit vs 32bit problem with the .NET Replication Management Objects 
(RMO). I am loading the RMO and Replication assemblies. The RMO 
assembly loads the MSIL version, but the Replication assembly is only 
available in either X86 or X64.

The problem that I am having is that the 
Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.TransSynchronizationAgent Class is not 
available when I run my script on a 64bit machine.  When I run it on a 
32bit machine it works fine.

When I try to create a new-object of that Class on a 64bit machine, I 
get an error that the Class is not registered. I looked in the 
registry and the Class is registered with the GAC in both 64bit and 
32bit(Wow6432Node) locations.

Has anyone ever experienced this issue before? Any ideas on a fix?

Thank you, 
Rickey

Comment: What happens when you run the x86 PowerShell.exe? Does it still complain?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar x64 vs x32 bit issue with Powershell recently. Its related to Windows Filesystem Redirection (more info here: http://practicaladmin.wordpress.com/2010/07/16/powershell-x64-and-filesystem-redirection/)

If you try to instantiate a 64bit Powershell instance from within a 32bit memory space (32bit PID or a PID running in 32bit mode/etc), Windows tries to "do the right thing" and executes the 32bit version of Powershell (in the syswow64 folder - yes, the 32bit powershell lives in the syswow64 folder).

Try running the 64bit version of Powershell.exe explicitly on the 64bit box using the following path:

```
%windir%\sysnative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```